# How to run in a loop on array in bash and check if element is empty

Tags: bash

I can check if variable is empty:

```
var=("")

if [[ -z "${var}" ]];
then
    echo "variable is empty"
else
    echo "variable is not empty"
fi
```

**Output:**

```
variable is empty
```

But when I try to apply it to an element in an array, I get no output:

```
array=("")

for i in ${array[@]}
do
    if [[ -z "${i}" ]];
    then
        echo "element in array is empty"
    else
        echo "element in array is not empty"
    fi
done
```

Comment: Since you don't double quote the `${array[@]}`, it is a subject to word-splitting and your loop does not iterate at all. Double quote it.

Answer (score 0):

since there is no element it doesn't get into the for loop. That is why no output is written to stdout.

think this like:

```
while(there is record)
   loop
```

since you don't have record in your array, It directly exits

Check this code

```
array=("1" "2" "" "3")

for i in "${array[@]}"
do
    if [[ -z "${i}" ]];
    then
        echo "element in array is empty"
    else
        echo "element in array is not empty : $i"
    fi
done
```

[Fiddle](https://rextester.com/ITFMDF38870)

Comment: thanks, but even  if I add some elements is to the array , it still does not recognize empty element.   for example: array=("a " " " "c")

for i in ${array[@]}
do
    echo ${i}
    if [[ -z "${i}" ]];
    then
        echo "element in array is empty"
    else
        echo "element in array is not empty"
    fi
done

Comment: check my edited answer please

Comment: got it, I had to add double quotes to the array, thanks :)!

Comment: If this answer is usefull for you please consider to upvote and/or mark it as answer. Thank you

Comment: Actually, if the OP accepts this answer, the question can't be [deleted automatically](/help/roomba) so I'm a bit divided here. It would be nice if you were rewarded for your effort, but it would also be nice if this 7.3E+05:th duplicate of this common FAQ could be removed from Stack Overflow.

Comment: @tripleee, I just wanted to help. Of course I will be happy  if my answer is rewarded with accepted answer or up-vote. However OP is not around here I believe. If the post needed to be deleted, this won't be problem anymore